# C# MongoDb SortBy enum

Tags: c#, .net-core, mongodb-.net-driver

is there any way to `SortBy` using an enum with the MongoDB driver?
I was trying this way but it seems it's not possible to use the same approach as LINQ.

```
 internal static readonly Dictionary<VehicleAvailabilityStatus, int> enumOrder =
            new Dictionary<VehicleAvailabilityStatus, int>
            {
                {VehicleAvailabilityStatus.Available, 1},
                {VehicleAvailabilityStatus.Reserved, 2},
                {VehicleAvailabilityStatus.NotAvailable, 3},
            };
public async Task<VehicleSearchResult> Search()
        {
            var vehicleCollection = DbContext.GetCollection<Vehicle>();
            var fb = new FilterDefinitionBuilder<Vehicle>();
            var filter = fb.Empty;
            var result = await vehicleCollection.Find(filter).SortBy(x => enumOrder[x.AvailabilityStatus]).ToListAsync();
            return new VehicleSearchResult(result);
        }
```

The Enum is not ordered as I want, so I need to change the order.

Answer (score 0):

Usually in Mongo Entities you can set your Enum Properties as int with decorations in your POCO .. like:

```
 [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.Int32)]
public AvailabilityStatus AvailabilityStatus{ get; set; }
```

So it will be stored in MongoDB as int ... then you can Sort (or OrderBy with Linq) by this field...

`Another` way  could be ... do your Query .. Hit it .. `and the Sort in MEMORY`

Hope it helps you!

Comment: the problem is that I want to change the order given in the enum, if the enum has 2 elements and the first is 0 and the other is 1 for example, i want 1 to be the first, and the other the second, obviously I need to map these in a more complex way, so changing from DESC to ASC is not an option. I also don't want to do it in memory